# how to merge two data based on one

Tags: bash, unix

I have two data saved at .txt in a folder

data1 which is called data 1 includes of one column data as follows

```
from
A0A0A6YXQ7
A0A0A6YXS5
A0A0A6YXW8
A0A0A6YXX6
A0A0A6YXZ1
A0A0A6YY28
A0A0A6YY43
A0A0A6YY47
A0A0A6YY78
A0A0A6YY89
A0A0A6YY91
A0A0A7NQN9
```

and the second data has two columns `from`and `to`

```
from    to
A0A0A6YXQ7  Myo1f
A0A0A6YXW8  Pak2
A0A0A6YXX6  Arhgap15
A0A0A6YXZ1  Igtp
A0A0A6YY28  pol
A0A0A6YY47  MumuTL
A0A0A6YY78  MumuTL
A0A0A6YY78  MumuTLM
A0A0A6YY91  MumuTL
A0A0A6YY91  MumuTLM
```

data1 and data2 have a column named `from` 
all strings in data1 should be in data2. if they are not.

I want to load the two data, and if the any string does not exist in the data2, I want to put it there as data1

for example, in data2 the following strings are missing

A0A0A6YXS5 and A0A0A6YY43 and A0A0A6YY89 and A0A0A7NQN9

so the output will look like this

```
From       To
A0A0A6YXQ7  Myo1f
A0A0A6YXS5  -
A0A0A6YXW8  Pak2
A0A0A6YXX6  Arhgap15
A0A0A6YXZ1  Igtp
A0A0A6YY28  pol
A0A0A6YY43  -
A0A0A6YY47  MumuTL
A0A0A6YY78  MumuTL;MumuTLM
A0A0A6YY89  -
A0A0A6YY91  MumuTL;MumuTLM
A0A0A7NQN9  -
```

Comment: Pplease show your coding efforts.

Comment: search here for `[linux] join` and see review `man join`. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A hash

# scan in file2 and make a key-value(s) table
while read line; do
    set -- $line
    if [ -z ${hash[$1]} ]; then
        hash[$1]=$2
    else
        hash[$1]="${hash[$1]};$2"
    fi
done < data2

# read file1 as keys and print appropriate value(s)
while read line; do
    if [ -z ${hash[$line]} ]; then
        echo $line "-"
    else
        echo $line ${hash[$line]}
    fi
done < data1
```

Note that "from" and "to" pair are accidentally properly processed.
Hope this helps.